VBS to run macro - VBS error, leaves Excel open, crashes PC
Task:  Customer has Azure SQL server, needs to export a table, grab 4 columns, change 0s to 1s, save to a specific location as a CSV, to be uploaded to a 3rd party site.  The upload part is a separate task, but works flawlessly.
Created the macro needed to do the work, and when ran manually, does everything needed.  Adjusted it to close Excel when done.  So onto automating it.
Using a very common VBS script found here, changed the variables, saved it as a VBS file, and when it runs, I get an error found below, as well as it saving the original file in the macro CSV file location.
Script Error Image
Line 19: 'Execute Macro Code
Line 20:  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath
Decided to try task scheduler as the examples showed.  Seems like it was going to work, but if the PC is restarted, it runs once, leaves excel open and eventually crashes
So I'd like to get suggestions on fixes/improvements, and hopefully I'll understand and follow along
In closing:
Manually running the macro in Excel, works perfectly every time, even closing Excel when completed.
Running the ExcelRun.bat file manually, presents an error referring to the ExcelApp.Run MacroPath, leaves Excel running, prevents the next attempt because file is set to Read-Only.
Running the TimeClockScript.vbs file, results in the same as above outcome.
I have 3 ways to run it, the more manual, the more successful.
I've read this site for days now, and yall are so much more advanced, that this stuff just rolls out your head and everyone understands, but me, nope, I don't quite get what is not working and/or why.
ExcelRun.bat

wscript.exe "C:\245942-1\Excel Run File\TimeClockScript.vbs"


TimeClockScript.vbs

'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "C:\245942-1\Excel Run File\smWorkOrders.xlsm"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "Module1.CopyColumnsToNewSheet"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = True  'or "False"

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.Save

'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

Excel Macro - CopyColumnsToNewSheet
Sub CopyColumnsToNewSheet()
'
' CopyColumnsToNewSheet Macro
'
'
' Refreshing table
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Columns("QI:QI").Select
    Range("QI:QI,C:C,F:F").Select
    Range("SMWorkOrder[[#Headers],[ServiceSite]]").Activate
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=1
    Range("QI:QI,C:C,F:F,S:S").Select
    Range("SMWorkOrder[[#Headers],[WOStatus]]").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:\245942-1\files\CostCodes"
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\245942-1\files\CostCodes\CostCodes.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, _
        CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Column3"
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="A", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="A", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
 End Sub


The error code 800A9C68 typically indicates an "Unknown runtime error" that might occur due to an issue with the VBS script syntax or a problem with the specified macro path.

Ensure that the macro name "Module1.CopyColumnsToNewSheet" is correct. It should match exactly with the macro’s name in Excel. Try running the macro directly within Excel to confirm that CopyColumnsToNewSheet executes without errors.

Fully qualify the macro path: ExcelApp.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Module1.CopyColumnsToNewSheet"

If the Excel workbook is already open by another process or was left open from a previous failed run, the script might encounter issues. Close all instances of Excel or restart the system to ensure no open files.
Error Handling:

Add error handling to the VBS script to capture and print errors:


    On Error Resume Next
    ExcelApp.Run MacroPath
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error running macro: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


I've used #2 and appreciate the example.  I'm looking at the #4, but not sure where to add it, logic states it would be at the end, so trying that today.

Just added the error handling, error still persists.

Also, 'User must be logged on' to run, otherwise, wont' run.  If I select to run whether a user is logged on or not, it will not run.
